# Is there any ways to attach some debug fields for a rust struct?

Tags: rust

For example, I want struct `S` to have a `name_count` field only when testing, so I can manipulate `last_name` to validate some properties about `name_count` in tests.

```
pub struct S {
    last_name: String,
    #[cfg(test)] {
        // This field only exists in tests
        name_count: HashMap<String, i32>,
    }
}

impl S {
    fn record_last_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.last_name = name;
        if cfg!(test) {
            // Increase self.name_count[self.last_name]
        }
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_last_name_count() {
    let mut s = S {};
    ...
    // assert some properties about name_count
}
```

However, this code can't compile, seems Rust don't support a `#[cfg(test)]` inside definition of a struct, so I wonder how can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that, but `#[cfg(test)]` is an attribute macro, so it applies to whatever follows it, and doesn't need a block scope like you had written it.

You also need add the `#[cfg(...)]` attributes to functions and methods to make sure you don't get "missing field"/"no field named ..." compiler errors.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub struct S {
    last_name: String,
    #[cfg(test)]
    // This field only exists in tests
    name_count: HashMap<String, i32>,
}

impl S {
    #[cfg(test)]
    fn record_last_name(&mut self, name: String) {
        self.last_name = name;
        // Increase self.name_count[self.last_name]
    }
}

#[cfg(not(test))]
fn main() {
    let mut s = S { last_name: "Foo".to_string() };
}

#[test]
fn test_last_name_count() {
    let mut s = S { last_name: "Foo".to_string(), name_count: HashMap::new() };
    // assert some properties about name_count
}
```

Comment: You cannot use `if cfg!()` with this definition, you have to use `#[cfg()]`.

Comment: You can put the `#[cfg()]` on the statement alone, no need to gate the whole function.

Comment: Do you mean for `main` or `record_last_name`? I think `main` probably needs it on the function unless they want to manage an `s` for both configurations. I left it function scope in the impl block just to avoid assumptions about what they needed the method to do, but yeah, that one could go on an expression.